# How to include term custom meta into the custom taxonomy term permalink structure

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, permalinks, terms, term-meta

I made a custom taxonomy and I'm trying to customise the permalink structure for each term by using term custom meta. At the moment I have a custom post type `magazine_article` and a custom taxonomy `magazine`.

My aim is to get a structure as follows:

- /magazines/  archive for magazine_article post type served by
  archive-magazine_article.php
- /magazines/15/ for term archive served
  by taxonomy-magazine.php
- /magazines/15/linus-interview/ for single
  magazine_article served by single-magazine_article.php

I got all of them working nicely except for the term archive (second bullet).

As a matter of fact, the term name is something like 'foo bar' which originally outputs a permalink such as '/magazines/foo-bar/' and I have a term custom meta with a value that I need for the rewrite for example '15'

I tried this:

on `Class Magazine_Taxonomy`

```
public function edit_term_permalink($url, $term, $taxonomy) {
    if ($taxonomy == self::$mag_taxonomy_slug) {
        $meta = get_term_meta($term->term_id, self::$mag_no_key);
        $mag_no = $meta[0];
        $url1 = explode('magazines/', $url);
        $url2 = $url1[0] . 'magazines/' . $mag_no . '/';
        return $url2;
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Then on my Manager class:

```
$this->loader->add_filter('term_link', $magazine_taxonomy, 'edit_term_permalink', 10, 3);
```

**When using `get_term_link()` for a term of the magazine taxonomy I get exactly what I want**, even on the backend the terms 'view' links give me the correct link. But the link doesn't work. It seems like if I'm modifying the link that wordpress gives me but without registering it within its rewrite rules.

However, only the original 'magazines/hello-world/' **does work**.

I went on Settings > Permalinks multiple times, restarted the server, deleted the .htaccess file and nothing seems to work. I ran out of ideas on how to make this work so I guess that the filter `term_link` does not do what I want. How could I achieve this ?